# KerberosSecurityTokenProvider in System.IdentityModel.dll

Tags: c#, .net, single-sign-on, kerberos, wcf-security

Can this api be used for getting service tokens for a particular serviceprincipalname to support kerberos authentication in wpf app.
This app will consuming http service that has kerberos authentication enabled.
If yes what are the downsides of this API.?
I have this question because kerberos.Net library and Microsoft's SSPI API are designed to work with kerberos authentication protocol also.

Answer (score 0):

You may use SSPI instead of using Kerberos directly.It knows who initiated the security context.

The following link is an introduction to SSPI:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/rpc/sspi-architectural-overview

Comment: Did  look at tate document. Buti would have to write c# wrappers to use these APIs in WPF to communicate with kerberos enabled http service. But mentioned class does consume SSPI  o do kerberos authentication.  Can be used directly?t

Comment: I'm not sure about WPF, you can try SSPI.